# How to fit Probability distribution to this data. Using scipy

Tags: scipy, probability, gamma-distribution

I have a data like this :

[image: dataframe]

I have plotted histogram for each month :

[image: histogram]

I can not seem to fig out which probability distribution will fit it the most. 
I tried to fit in gamma distribution but results are bad :

```
alpha_mom = precip_mean ** 2 / precip_var
beta_mom = precip_var / precip_mean
from scipy.stats.distributions import gamma

unemployment.Jan.hist(normed=True, bins=20)
plt.plot(np.linspace(0, 10), gamma.pdf(np.linspace(0, 10), alpha_mom[2], 
beta_mom[2]))
```

Can someone guide me which distribution will fir above data. I could not seem to figure out. 
here are result for fitting for month of Jan:
[image: results]

Comment: Instead of computing histograms it is more appropriate to compute the ECDF for each month. This should give you a better idea what distribution function to use.

Comment: @KRKirov I tried doing it but i could not find a way on how to do it with my dataframe. can you  point me out how can i do that

Comment: In order to compute the ECDF for each month, you need to: 1) Sort the data in each month in ascending order, e.g. np.sort(data).  This is the x-data of the ECDF. 2) np.arange(1, n+1)/n where n = len(data). This is the y-data of the ECDF.

Comment: @KRKirov Thank you i will try